# Difference between ionic serve and loading the index directly

Tags: ionic-framework

New to `ionic` I am having a play and have come across this issue. I have created an app that runs an `XMLHttpRequest` to get some data from a secure site. If I load the app's index.html file directly the data loads fine but not if I run `ionic serve`. The error is, I think, because the request is coming from localhost as on inspection I see the error.

> Origin http://localhost:8100 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

I am interested to know if I am going to run into `ionic` specific issues if I continue testing the app directly from the index file, and/or is there a way of allowing the `ionic serve` method access the data?

Code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
        <title></title>

        <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
        <script src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
      </head>

      <body ng-app="starter">

        <ion-pane>
          <ion-header-bar class="bar-calm">
            <button class="button icon ion-navicon button button-clear"></button>
            <h1 class="title">Log</h1>
            <button class="button icon ion-gear-b button button-clear"></button>
          </ion-header-bar>

          <ion-content>

          <script type="text/javascript">
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var url = "https://xxxxx/getLog.php";

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById('listLog').innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
              }
            };

            xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
            xmlhttp.send();
          </script>

          <p id="listLog"></p>

          </ion-content>
        </ion-pane>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Is your path for `index.html` absolute? I suspect you are trying to load `file://(path here)/index.html` from `http://localhost:8100` or vice versa. If so, changing it to relative paths should fix it

Comment: The index.html is in a folder on my desktop. Double clicking on it is fine and the data loads. It is when I use the ionic serve command from Terminal that the page loads without the data.

Comment: Would you mind pasting your code for loading `index.html`? My original question still stands and if you can provide me with some code it would be very helpful indeed

Comment: I have added the code.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same issue by installing **[Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en)** plugin in my Google Chrome.